# Unity - prevent objects from bouncing SO FAR off when colliding at short distance?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, collider

Ok, what Im trying to do is make a huge pile of objects, procedurally. What Ive done is have 1 copy of my object in the container empty (with script), then add all these objects to a list while cloning each a random num of times.

Each object has a Box collider and Rigidbody with gravity. I need both so that object falls on top of others but not thru the floor.

I clone and position each object in a random position within a sphere:

```
foreach(Transform t in transform)
        {


            if (t.name != "PileSphere")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Random.Range(minOfEach, maxOfEach); i++)
                {
                    GameObject g = Instantiate(t.gameObject);
                    spawnObjs.Add(g);
                }
                spawnObjs.Add(t.gameObject);
            }
            else
            {
                sphere = t.gameObject;
            }
        }

        foreach(GameObject g in spawnObjs)
        {

            Vector3 radius = Random.insideUnitSphere * 10 +transform.position;
            //g.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-10, 10), 0, Random.Range(-10, 10));
            g.transform.position = radius;
        }
```

This works, however I press play and none of the objects remain in the space I instantiated them, because they bounce many meters off each other, despite setting the bounce threshold high:

[image]

What can I do to create a random pile of movable objects?

Comment: If you remove the RigidBody, they won't bounce off. So why don't you figure out a way to make them fall without using the rigid body and gravity?

Answer (score 0):

If you're instantiating them inside each others' colliders, the physics engine will add an almost explosive outward force, because it is adding velocity each frame they're in contact. Make sure that none of your colliders are touching when spawned. You can't spawn them all in the same spot. You can arrange them into a pile and make that whole pile a prefab and instantiate that, or you can instantiate them at different heights, and let them land on each other.

If you use the prefab, you can then unparent the separate objects so they are not stuck together.

Comment: Ok, is there any way, when Im positioning them to further reduce the bounce off power/impact?